# How to make gnome-control-panel run on awesomewm?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, awesome, tiling

Gnome control panel does not properly run on awesomewm. Before GNOME 3, I used to run something called gnome-settings-daemon to get stuff like this working. How do I do this with GNOME 3, so that I can access my Ubuntu settings when running awesomewm? Should I maybe try a Xubuntu-based equivalent approach?